# How do I remove the plastic at the tip of my faucet handle?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plastic

My faucet handle has a plastic "lid" on the tip and I cannot remove it. I have tried prying it out, but I'm scared I will damage the plastic. Please help!!

[image][image]

Comment: Flat blade object, screwdriver, tweezers, butter knife.

Comment: It may be threaded hard to see in the photo. A pair of needle nose pliers open and used like a spanner wrench may help unscrew it.

Comment: A decent photo would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your title and text say *faucet handle* but your photo shows a plastic object in your *faucet spout*. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It will pry out, you will need a razor knife with a heavy duty blade to start the gap to finish prying it out.

Answer (score 0):

A Thin bladed regular (flat blade) screw driver will pry it out - some of them have a good pry spot - search around the side of the lid for a small indention under the top of the lid. Place the screw driver there and then pry.